# Specific path in a gradient field of a saddle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I think this is a classic question but I could not find a useful reference to understand it so I post it.

Take the classic saddle $z=x^2-y^2$. When you sit over it in $(0,0)$ you see in front of you that the function rises and your legs are over a parabola which is the less wide one.

Now take a more complicated saddle-like function such as $z=(3x+3y)^2-(4x+y)^2$. In this way the saddle isn't symmetric and I want to determine the curve which has the same role of the "less wide parabola" of the first case (so where to put my legs comfortably in a certain sense)

I thought that a possible solution could be to calculate the gradient field (which is immediate since only derivations are needed) and then determine the path which goes through the "steepest descent" through the gradients. So this path is the curve I'm looking for (the equivalent of the "less wide parabola").

Is the approach to my problem correct?

How do I calculate analytically the steepest descent?

Indeed I need a procedure that can be applied to more complicated functions than the two mentioned.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First calculate the Hessian matrix at your saddle point $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0)$,

$$
H(f)(x_0,y_0) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) & f_{xy}(x_0,y_0) \\
f_{yx}(x_0,y_0) & f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)
\end{array}\right).
$$

If the saddle point is nondegenerate this will have one positive and one negative eigenvalue.  The eigenvector associated with the negative eigenvalue is tangent to the path of steepest descent from the saddle and the eigenvector associated with the positive eigenvalue is tangent to the path of steepest ascent.

For your example

$$
g(x,y) = (3x+3y)^2-(4x+y)^2
$$

we have

$$
H(g)(0,0) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -14 & 10 \\
 10 & 16
\end{array}
\right),
$$

which has eigenvalues $\lambda_{\pm} = 1 \pm 5\sqrt{13}$ with associated eigenvectors

$$
\mathbf{v}_{\pm} = \left(\frac{1\pm 5\sqrt{13}}{10} - \frac{8}{5},1\right).
$$

So the path of steepest ascent is tangent to $\mathbf{v}_+$ and the path of steepest descent is tangent to $\mathbf{v}_-$.

Below is a plot showing the straight line in the direction of $\mathbf{v}_+$ in $\color{red} {\text{red}}$ and the straight line in the direction of $\mathbf{v}_-$ in $\color{blue} {\text{blue}}$ on the graph of $g(x,y)$.

[image]

If your saddle is degenerate then you will need to look at [higher-order coefficients in the Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansion#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) of $f$ centered at the saddle.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can I ask you the equations for the blue and red line (and so how did you find them)? So I can check my result because at the moment I'm using a bad program to draw mathematical functions.

Comment: @edwineveningfall In the $x,y$-plane the blue line is described parametrically by $\mathbf{r}(t) = t \mathbf{v}_-$.  In the image I projected it onto the graph of $g$ by giving it an appropriate $z$ coordinate.  The parameterization for the resulting 3D curve is $\mathbf{s}(t) = (\mathbf{r}(t),g \circ \mathbf{r}(t))$.  The red line is parameterized similarly but with $\mathbf{v}_+$ instead of $\mathbf{v}_-$.  Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Perfect! I really need to change software. Thank you again!